Understanding the formula for preAllocatedVUs?
In this k6 documentation https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/using-k6/scenarios/concepts/arrival-rate-vu-allocation/, there is a formula for preallocated VUs or virtual users
preAllocatedVUs = [median_iteration_duration * rate] + constant_for_variance

I don't understand how they came up with this formula. Can someone please explain it to me with an actual example(s) ? If I need 30 iterations per second for 30 seconds, then do I always need 30 or more preAllocatedVUs or can I use less ?

A VU can participate in only one transaction at a time and is blocked for the duration of the iteration. So, median_iteration_duration is the (median) duration for which each VU will be occupied.
If one iteration takes 2 seconds, then to sustain the rate of 1 iter/s, you'll need 2 x 1 = 2 VUs since one VU can only execute maximum 0.5 iter/s.
Similarly, 30 iter/s will require 2 x 30 = 60 VUs.
Extra constant term is added to count for variance in load, since we're working with median iteration duration.

Thanks. To find the value of median_iteration_duration for an api, do we have to conduct experiments and then maybe add some margin of safety ?

Yes. You can run a small test load on the API and the results will have iteration_duration metric with med value.
